# triple integration for a box in R: numerical error

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I'm trying to figure out how to reliably compute the mass of a solid with varying density which I am modeling using a regression function.

My box has the following dimensions:

```
w = 50
l = 150
h = 15
```

To help me gain intuition for using the numerical integrator in `pracma`, I imagined that the box had two density regions (h < 10 -> 50, h >= 10 -> 100).

```
l*w*(5*100 + 10*50) # => 7500000
```

Yet when I pass this to the numerical integrator I get:

```
library(pracma)
density = function(x, y, z) ifelse(z > 10, 100, 50)
integral3(density, xmin = 0, xmax = 50, ymin = 0, ymax = 150, zmin = 0, zmax = 15)
```

This returns `7530340`. Can you help give me some intuition for what is happening here and how I might improve the computation of the integral?

Comment: From what I know, a lot of numerical methods assume smooth functions and use some rule to approximate the intergral based on that function. Here, you have a sharp change in density which is probably what's causing the issue

Comment: Try a different package, for instance *cubature*. Its `adaptIntegrate` will give much more accurate results, even for step functions like your test example.